# Automatically generate HTTP request URLs in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have an API call URL similar to this:

> `http://domain.com/rest/getValues?apiKey=sdfsdf&customerId=2200&timestampBegin=2013-08-15%2018:00:00%20CEST&timestampEnd=2013-08-19%2018:00:00%20CEST`

I would like to dynamically change the time stamps, as well as the customerId, picked from a given set of timestamps and customerIds. Is this possible to do in Jmeter (preferably through GUI)?

Comment: @fujy The given URL. I hope my edit made it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are have inputs coming from external CSV file, you can use CSV data set config as explained [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config).

Your test plan will look something like

- Thread groups

  - CSV Data Set config (define the file path and the variable names. You will be able to read these variables in request.
  - HTTP Sampler

    - http://domain.com/rest/getValues?apiKey=sdfsdf&customerId=${custid}&timestampBegin=${begin}&timestampEnd=${end}